# awk command to go to a specific line in a file that contains the word

Tags: shell, awk

I am writing an awk script wherin I want to search for some strings in a file.The problem I am facing is ...

The file is extremely huge, in the sense .. Around 1 million lines .

If I search for a string which is present at the last line of the file, then I have unnecessarily traversed the rest of the beginning lines and hence I am looking for some command which when I give the string as an argument, it should give me the line number of the file .. Or I would like to do a binary search on the file, any redirection regarding this .

Just an additional note, the string is not a single string, I have multiple strings to search at one point of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what you do, if the data is in a file, it will have to be read into memory before you can do any processing (no matter how efficient), sorting, searching, etc.

Are you running out of memory, or are you concerned about time?  If memory isn't an issue, 1 million records don't seem that big these days.

If you just want to determine if a certain string is present in your data file, you could try use `grep`. E.g.,

```
 grep -n target_string data.txt
```

will print the line and line number if the target was found in the file. More information on the [grep man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

If you want to locate and then *process* a line in the file, then `grep` won't work, and you'll have to use `awk` (like you mentioned), or look at `sed` or writing a custom script in Python or some other language. In all cases, the file will have to be read one way or the other.

Perhaps breaking the file into chunks and then processing a specific part (if you can determine ahead of time where to search - though that sound unlikely from your question)

Comment: I am concerned about time and not memory

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but will I be able to use grep inside the awk command ?

Comment: @NandaKumar Do you want to do more processing after you find the line number? `grep` also reads the whole file, so I'm not sure there's much to be gained putting it *inside* `awk`. If you need to *find* and then *process* a specific line, you'll have to use the tools I mention in my updated answer.

Comment: I accept your point ... As you said its true that the file has to be read one way or the other ....

Answer (score 0):

You have one million lines, but how big is the file? One million lines of 1 char a line gives a file size of ~1MB, which is tiny and in terms of time will take no time to parse. 80 chars/line gives a file size of 76MB which will take more time to read than the 1 char/line file, but the time will not be horrendous for a simple find.

If you're looking at many megabytes, then you need to read the file once and create an index of it, however if this is a one-off or rare task, the time taken to create such an index will not outweigh the cost of doing searches directly against the file with `grep` or `awk`.

Similarly, if you need to do this against files that are constantly changing, again having an index will not gain you much as the index will be out of date and you'd need to refresh the index (requiring a rescan of the full file) to get accurate results.

We'd need more details of the overarching problem as it sounds like there's some other requirement(s) that aren't clear: how often do you do this search? How static is the file? What do you do with the result? In short, for what need/application are you doing this?

That said, if you wanted to create an index, then it's simply a case of reading the file in line by line, splitting at white-space, then storing in some datastore (SQLite database? BDB database?) the word along with the line it appears on, then querying that store directly. Hopefully you can see that the initial generation is quite expensive so this is only worth doing if the file is static and you're doing many searches against the file.

Answer (score 0):

You mention doing a binary search on the file, so we can assume your input is sorted and the strings you are looking for are anchored to the start of the line.  To do a binary search, there is a utility called `look`, but it does not report the line number.  To get the line number,  simply append line numbers to the input:

```
# Append line numbers to each line
$ awk '{print $0, NR}' input > tmp   

# Do a binary search, looking for the string 'string'
$ look string tmp
```

`look` and `seq` are not standard utilities, so may not be available on your platform.